# Finite sums of prime numbers $\geq x$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $S_x$ be the set of finite sums of prime numbers $\geq x$. In other words, let $S_x$ be the submonoid of $(\mathbf{Z}_{\geq 0},+)$ generated by the set $\mathcal{P}_{\geq x}$ of prime numbers $\geq x$.

It is easy to see that $S_x$ contains every sufficiently large integer. This follows from the classical fact that given two coprime integers $a$ and $b$, every sufficiently large integer, in fact every integer $\geq (a-1)(b-1)$, is of the form $ma+nb$ for some $m, n \in \mathbf{Z}_{\geq 0}$. See for example [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Let $N_x$ be the largest integer which is not in $S_x$.

**Examples** :

If $x=2$ then $S_2 = \{0\} \cup \mathbf{N}_{\geq 2}$ so that $N_2=1$.

If $x=3$ then $S_3 = \{0,3\} \cup \mathbf{N}_{\geq 5}$ so that $N_3=4$.

By definition, we have $N_x \geq x-1$ (in fact parity considerations imply that $N_x \geq 2x-2$ for $x \geq 3$).

On the other hand, given that there are at least two primes in the interval $[x,2x]$, the above classical fact implies that $N_x \ll x^2$.

> What is the asymptotic behaviour of $N_x$ as $x \to \infty$ ?

Comment: Interesting question! This is essentially Sloane's A180306, but it does not contain any information on the asymptotics. 

Comment: @Charles : Thanks for the reference to Sloane's database. @Mark : I don't really know. I suspect that the upper bound I gave is much too high, but I don't know what to expect since I'm not a specialist in additive number theory.

Comment: Lemma 1 of Erdos's 1974 paper with Benkoski "On weird and pseudoperfect numbers" is: 

There is an absolute constant $c$ such that every integer $m > c p_k$ is the distinct sum of primes not less than $p_k$.

(Here $p_k$ is the $k$th prime, in the usual order.) No proof is given. "The lemma is probably well known and, in any case, easily follows by Brun's method."

Comment: @Anonymous : Thanks for the reference! It would be interesting to make $c$ explicit.

Comment: In view of the answers below indicating the link with Goldbach's conjecture, which is out of reach, I would accept any answer showing that $N_x \ll x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to "The three primes theorem with almost equal summands" by Baker and Harman, every large odd $N$ is a sum of three primes each of size $\sim N/3$. (In fact, within $N^{4/7}$ of $N/3$-- this is much closer than we need, so we could use weaker results of earlier authors, if preferred.)

For odd $N$, this gives $N$ as a sum of three primes, each at least $\sim N/3$. If $N$ is even, take a prime $p$ of size $\sim N/4$ (which exists by the prime number theorem), and write $N-p$ as a sum of three primes of size about $N/4$. So we get $N$ as a sum of four primes at least $\sim N/4$.

Comment: Thanks! This result indeed shows that $N_x/x$ is bounded (and in fact $\operatorname{limsup} N_x/x \leq 4$).

Answer (score 6):

(Edited according to the comments below)

In his article titled 'Sums of Distinct Primes', Kløve conjectured, on the basis of computational evidence, that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{N_x}{x} = 3$. This would imply the binary Goldbach conjecture (for large enough $x$) in the following way: if every integer larger than $(3 + \epsilon)x$ can be written as sum of primes, where those primes are all larger than $x$, then, in particular, every even number between $(3 + \epsilon)x$ and $4x$ can be written as a sum of two primes.

Comment: @Woett: In that paper, the word "prime" does not appear. 

Comment: Hmm, maybe I understand the question wrong. Please read page 56 of the article of Erdos and Graham (page 52 of this pdf: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/80_11_number_theory.pdf)

Comment: I had noticed the limit numerically, but didn't know the Goldbach connection.  Thanks!

Comment: @Woett: I agree with Mark, "prime" does not occur in Kløve's paper (aside from the references). It looks like Erdos & Graham are wrong about the paper if not the conjecture; after a quick read though I did not see any mention of this problem.

Comment: Maybe they mean the 1973 article of Kløve, titled "Sums of distinct primes"?

Comment: For those of us who are slow on the uptake, K's conjecture implies ternary Goldbach, not binary,  right?  Gerhard "One, Two, Many, Ha HaHa" Paseman, 2012.04.03

Comment: @Woett: Yes, Kløve, Torleiv Sums of distinct primes. 
Nordisk Mat. Tidskr. 21 (1973), 138–140. According to Math Reviews he conjectured there that the limit is 3. The review does not mention Goldbach. The paper is not on-line, unfortunately. 

Comment: I don't see either. Since this is an asymptotic statement, I find it hard to believe it would imply anything better than "the conjecture holds for all sufficiently large numbers", but we already know this unconditionally for the weak GC.

Comment: No, it also implies binary Goldbach. If every number larger than $(3 + \epsilon)n$ can be written as a sum of primes that are all larger than $n$, then every even number between $(3 + \epsilon)n$ and $4n$ must be a sum of two primes.

Comment: @Woett: Your argument shows that every sufficiently large even number is a sum of two primes. How do you get rid of the finitely many potential exceptions?

Comment: yeah, I meant to say 'binary Goldbach for all large enough values'. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Does Vinogradov result that every sufficiently large odd number is a sum of three primes imply that the limit is at most 5 (or at least $< \infty$)? Vinogradov does not claim that his primes are all of approximately the same size, but perhaps his method can be adapted to produce such a result.  

Comment: I very much do believe that it is possible to prove that the limit is finite. But how to do that is probably beyond me. Conceivably Vinogradov's method or Schnirelmann's approach works.

Comment: There was a discussion on this thread ( http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82426/a-conjecture-on-the-relative-size-of-goldbach-pairs ) on the relative sizes of the primes in the binary Goldbach case.

Comment: Mark, Terry Tao posted a result on Arxiv that all odd numbers are the sum of at most 5 primes.  I believe his result is unconditional and relies on computations performed up to the first few billion numbers.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.03

Comment: Oops.  Another Emily Litella.  Oh well.  Gerhard "How About Those Goldberg Variations" Paseman, 2012.04.03

Comment: Thanks Woett for your answer and everyone for the comments. Kløve considers only sums of distinct primes. Does this make any difference for the conjectured limit of $N_x/x$ ?

Comment: @François: No, since not requiring the primes to be distinct can only make the limit lower, but the limit has to be at least 3 (there is an odd composite in $[3n-5,3n)$).

Answer (score 6):

Just to spell it out, If Golbach's conjecture is false, then at least once $N(x)>4x$, but that seems extremely unlikely. It is certain that $N(x)>3x$ infinitely often, but there is every reason to believe that $N(x)<(3+\epsilon)x$ with finitely many exceptions. If so, then we could equivalently define $N_x$ as the largest odd integer which is neither prime nor a sum of $3$ primes all at least $x$.

it will frequently happen that the next prime after $p$ is at least $p+8.$ In these cases we can write $3p$ as a sum of primes at least $x=p$ however at least one of the odd numbers $3p+2,3p+4,3p+6$ is not itself prime and hence not a  sum of primes all greater than $x=p.$ This establishes that $N(x)>3x$ infinitely often.

There is no proof that every even integer is a sum of two primes. Were there a counter-example, $E$, it would need to be a sum of at least 4 primes and hence furnish an example of $N(x)>4x$ where $x$ is $\frac{E}{4}.$ However there is every reason to  believe the stronger statement that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an $M(\epsilon)$ such that $2m$ is a sum of two primes, both larger than $m(1-\epsilon)$ for all $m \gt M(\epsilon).$ If so, then $N(x)<(3+\epsilon)x$ provided that $x$ is reasonably larger  $\frac{M(\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon}.$

Comment: Using $x = k! + 1$, we can even show that $\limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} N(x) - 3x = \infty$. In fact, using an estimate of Rankin on large prime gaps, we should get $N(x) - 3x > c\log x \log \log x \log \log \log \log x (\log \log \log x)^{-2}$ infinitely often.

Comment: However, does not rule out the possibility that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ we have  $\limsup_{x \to  \infty}N(x)-(3+\epsilon)x=-\infty$ 

Comment: Oh, of course not! Perhaps even $N(x) < 3x + x^{\epsilon}$ for large $x$. But this should be really far from what can be proven with current methods :)

Comment: True. With current methods we can not prove Golbach's conjecture so we do not know that $N(x) \lt 4x$ is true, although we believe it is. Were I foolish I would predict $(3+c_1/\ln{x})x \lt N(x) \lt (3+c_2/\ln{x})x.$ 

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your answer. I believe your argument shows that for any odd $x$ which is not prime, we have $N(x) \geq 3x$, since $3x$ cannot be written as a sum of primes $\geq x$.

Comment: Woett wrote that "$\displaystyle{lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{N(x)}{x}=3}$ would imply the binary Goldbach conjecture (for large enough $x$)". Is the converse true?

Comment: Maybe one could manage to prove that if the limit François asks about is an integer $n$, then this integer is the smallest $k$ such every integer greater than $1$ is the sum of $k$ primes. But a first step would be to prove that the limit actually exists.

Comment: Obviously, I meant "such that every integer greater than $1$ is the sum of at most $k$ primes".

Comment: @Sylvain : The converse is not obvious. The point is that we apparently need a version of Goldbach in which the primes are not too small.

Comment: I guess it means than if $2m=p+q$ with $p<q$ then $q-p$ must not be too large? Would a relation like $r_{0}(n)=O(\ln^{2} n)$, where $r_{0}(n)$ is the smallest $r$ such that both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are primes, be sufficient to establish that the limit we are interested in equals $3$?

Comment: @Sylvain : Yes, in fact $r_0(n) = o(n)$ would be enough.

Comment: Actually, I have a sketch of proof of the relation I mentioned in my previous comment, but I'm not sure of its correctness.

Comment: @Sylvain I'm not trying to discourage you, but be skeptical of such claims. And then some more. 

Comment: In fact, I am skeptical of it. That's why I need the advice of a specialist.