# Effective bound for odd numbers expressed as sums of three primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

I am interested in the representation of odd numbers greater than five as sums of three primes, inspired by Harald Helfgott's seminal proof of the ternary Goldbach conjecture and the nuanced findings of "[Vinogradov’s Theorem with Almost Equal Summands](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms.12040?casa_token=VvYijVK9B5kAAAAA:8_gfgOVcMbbsJaO0r798CKwLsigq5LbpahVjOmTgo62nk-VM0SM4Bk1-TAI2DCitChiEVjRUWnz68fo)" by Kaisa Matomäki, James Maynard, and Xuancheng Shao regarding summand sizes.

Here is the question: Is there an $N$ such that for every odd number $n>N$, there exists a representation $n = p_1+p_2+p_3$ with each prime $p_i$ satisfying
$$
\dfrac{n}{6} < p_i < \dfrac{n}{2}
$$
$N$=6 has been identified as a potential bound that works, suggesting its validity on an experimental basis.

However, is there a known effective bound $N$ for which all odd numbers greater than $N$ can be represented under these relatively weak (or similar) conditions? It's worth noting that explicit bounds in analytic number theory, when they are known, tend to be exceedingly high.

(The motivation lies in an investigation of numerical semigroups generated by primes, as discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93002/finite-sums-of-prime-numbers-geq-x))